# Помогите пожалуйста! Цикл выдает предупреждение:mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

Сам цикл работает. И делает то, что от него требуется. Но доп надпись на странице мешает.

```
while ($passlib = mysqli_fetch_assoc($admin)) {
    if (($log == $usernameX) && ($pas == $passwordX)) {
        break;
    } else {
        $usernameX = $passlib['name'];
        $passwordX = $passwordX['pass'];
    }
}
```

Как исправить? Подскажите, пожалуйста!
[полный код](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1M14484lw9EqQF8GnztB-Q2NXmWpyrhUt?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В переменной `$admin` у вас значение `null`, как сказано в ошибке. Сделайте так, чтоб там был результат выполнения запроса... **корректного запроса**

Comment: $admin = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `passwords`"); - это значение $admin

Comment: @Weily коннект значит кривой. если таблица такая и впрямь существует. смотри что в коннекте (mysqli_connect). Также Перед соединением с БД надо написать строчку `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` и смотреть что пхп будет писать реальную причину ошибки

Comment: @Weily обычно ругается на boolean given, а не null. Почему-то уверен, что ты где-то ещё переменной манипулируешь. Приведи полный код, без выковыриваний "лишнего" кода

Comment: добавил [вот еще](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1M14484lw9EqQF8GnztB-Q2NXmWpyrhUt?usp=sharing)

Comment: @Weily если я правильно понял - проблема что `mysqli_query` два раза подряд и никак не используешь. надо последовательно обработать вначале `$manu` а потом `$admin` хотя бы согласно докам https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php#refsect1-mysqli.query-examples